# Broke Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria accidentally

Tags: linux, linux-mint, python, python3

I am a new Linux user, switched from windows to linux just 2 days ago(like I made linux my main OS, removed windows completely). As I am a new user, I didn't have any snapshots of my system.

I was doing necessary installations but while installing python, I noticed the default version was old. I downloaded one using sudo but that wasn't the latest version too.

So, I downloaded the tarball file from the official website. I followed some online tutorials and figured out how to install the latest python version from the tarball file.

Now, while trying to set this new python version as my default, I broke my pc. Like it's loading, but gui terminal is not opening, the panel is not opening. Only the folders on dekstop are. Right Click>Terminal doesn't work either

I did ctrl+alt+f4 and opened the tty terminal. But there is a problem. When I open it, it shows:

```
Linux Mint 21.2 victoria cat tty4
cat login:
```

(cat is the username, changed it for privacy as it contained my real name)

I enter my user name Then I am prompted for password. However, I can't use type numbers or alphabets here.. even with numlock on. Note: I was able to type numbers and alphabets both when giving username.

I currently don't have an extra OS or something...I don't have a backup either...Please help me fix the issue...or else I have to go to my local computer store and install an OS again (no Linux anymore if I have to go to the store )

Comment: You can type, it's just not being displayed

Answer (score 1):

The reason your Mint install broke is that every system app that it runs is not only expecting a certain version of Python, but of its modules as well. I would strongly recommend (2) things:

1. reinstall Mint and leave the system python alone
2. read up on **pyenv**: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv. This will allow you to install just about any version of python you want, without affecting the system version.

Comment: Ok, but how to Reinstall my system? Can I do something from the terminal? Or do I again need a bootable usb for it?

Comment: I would go the bootable USB route. Just save your data first, of course.

Comment: Ok thanks, did it successfully